# Why can interactive Ruby run a program, but sublime editor not?

Tags: ruby

I wrote code like this:

```
class Animal
    attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
end
first_animal = animal.new 

first_animal.name  = "Floyd"
first_animal.color = "white"
first_animal.age = 7
puts first_animal.name
```

When I save it and drag onto "**command prompt with Ruby**" and press enter, it says `undefined local variable`, but when I write the code using interactive ruby (IRB terminal) it works fine. It shows me the results of `first_animal.name` etc. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax mistake:

`Animal.new` instead of `animal.new`

Comment: Oh my, thanks. Such a stupid mistake lol